# Como crear colisiones entre elementos sprites de un array

Tags: javascript, nodejs, phaser.io

He creado varios sprites con phaser y los he almacenado en un array.

```
function createShip(x,y,angle,ship){
            var s = game.add.sprite(x,y,ship);
            s.rotation = angle;
            s.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);
            return s;
        }



for(var i in data){
                    if(others[i] == undefined && i != socket.id){
                        var d = data[i];
                        others[i] = createShip(d.x,d.y,d.angle,d.ship);
                    }
                    found[i] = true;

                    if(i != socket.id){
                        others[i].x = data[i].x;
                        others[i].y = data[i].y;
                        others[i].rotation = data[i].angle;
                        others[i].ship = data[i].ship;
                    }
                }
```

he intento agregar estas lineas de codigo que vi en l documentacion de Phaser

```
game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
game.physics.arcade.enable(others);
```

y en la funcion Update

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(others);
```

en donde others es el array que almacena todos los sprites, pero esto aun no funciona

Answer (score 1):

No tengo la solución exacta a tu problema, pero te voy a presentar la forma en como yo creo las colisiones entre sprites en phaser. Espero te sea de ayuda.

1. Configura correctamente la física de Phaser.

```
game = new Phaser.Game({
    // ... El resto de las configuraciones ...
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: { 
            gravity: { y: 0 }, // Cambia la gravedad dependiendo de tu juego.
        }
    },
});
```

2. Crea los sprites de forma que ya vengan con un cuerpo físico listo para colisionar.

```
// Esto esta adentro de la función créate() de Phaser.

// Carro es un cuerpo dinamico. (básicamente que puede moverse, rebotar, etc..)
let carro = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 100, 'carro')

// Pared es un cuerpo estático. (no se mueve ni responde a las fuerzas externas)
let pared = this.physics.add.staticSprite(400, 100, 'pared')

// this.physics.add.sprite (añade un Sprite con un cuerpo físico).
// this.add.sprite (añade solamente la imagen, no tiene interacción física)
```

3. Crea la colisión entre los dos cuerpos y aparte establece la función que se va a ejecutar cuando eso ocurra.

```
// Esto esta adentro de la función créate() de Phaser.

// En phaser no se llama 'Collision' (Palabra en ingles) sino que se llama es 'Collider'.
this.physics.add.collider(carro, pared, () => {
    console.log('EL CARRO HA CHOCADO CONTRA LA PARED Y AHORA ESTA EN LLAMAS :C')
})
```

Comment: Excelente! solución! voy a darle una leida a phaser